# Object not falling down but instead going another direction

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I made a simple pinball machine and placed a pinball at the top. After applying rigid body physics to all objects, pinball is going in another direction instead of falling down. All other settings are default.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Please show your Blender work with screen captures placed in your question. Do so in the future as well.

Comment: Please show your axis and your gravity setting and any forces present.